# How can I prevent local administrators from looking at each others files?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a Windows 8 machine. All domain accounts are local administrators.

Currently, it is very easy for one administrator to look at the other users personal files simply by browsing to their personal folders and confirming that they want permanent access in the UAC prompt.

How do I prevent that, and restrict access for each administrator to their individual folder only?

Is there any official Microsoft way of keeping private between local administrators?

Comment: Don't give people you don't trust admin access.

Comment: Don't make them Administrators?

Comment: Can the thread be moved to Superuser?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder You'll get the same answer there.

Comment: Your edit does not change the answer, either.

Comment: I'd say User Shares could be safer. Only the admins of that server could access all the user folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

It is the nature of Administrator accounts to be able to do essentially everything.  Even if you change the file permissions to block "other" Administrator accounts from accessing certain files, they will be able to take ownership and give themselves permissions to access whatever files they want to.

Your only real option is to give everyone limited (non-Administrator) accounts.

Alternately, it is possible to enable file access auditing, and have those logs forwarded to another computer, so you can see who is accessing what, and that is usually sufficient to prevent people from snooping where they are not allowed, but when it gets right down to it, an Administrator account is an Administrator account.  It has, or can give itself, full access to everything, because that's what it's designed to do.

Comment: And there's this too... agree 100%, but at least if he uses my recommendation below, I'm assuming the users aren't smart enough to take ownership, although that doesn't mean that they won't someday.